# All of my data from columns of one file go into one column in my output file. How to keep it the same?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to delete some number of data rows from a file, essentially just because there are too many data points. I can easily print them to IDLE but when I try to write the lines to a file, all of the data from one row goes into one column. I'm definitely a noob but it seems like this should be "trivial"

I've tried it with writerow and writerows, zip(), with and without [], I've changed the delimiter and line terminator.

```py
import csv

filename = "velocity_result.csv"

with open(filename, "r") as source:
    for i, line in enumerate(source):
         if i % 2 == 0:
             with open ("result.csv", "ab") as result:
                result_writer = csv.writer(result, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
                result_writer.writerow([line])
```

This is what happens:

```
    input = |a|b|c|d| <row
           |e|f|g|h|
    output = |abcd|
                    <every other row deleted
    (just one column)
```

My expectaion is

```
    input = |a|b|c|d| <row
           |e|f|g|h|
    output = |a|b|c|d|
                       <every other row deleted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've read the line, it becomes a single item as far as Python is concerned. Sure, maybe it is a string which has comma separated values in it, but it is a single item still. So `[line]` is a list of 1 item, no matter how it is formatted.\

If you want to make sure the line is recognized as a list of separate values, you need to make it such, perhaps with split:

```
result_writer.writerow(line.split('<input file delimiter here>'))
```

Now the line becomes a list of 4 items, so it makes sense for csv writer to write them as 4 separated values in the file.

Comment: ah-ha! that makes sense. now to get rid of the extra line (but I think i have that one already!